# Why do I get the error 2 when I compile godot with the the visual script module?

Tags: godot

I get the error 2 when compiling the latest godot source version with the visual script module. Here's the error in the cmd :

[Initial build] Compiling thirdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\rescaler_sse2.c ...
[Initial build] scons: *** [modules\visual_script\register_types.windows.editor.x86_64.obj] Error 2
Compiling thirdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\ssim.c ...
modules\visual_script\editor\visual_script_property_selector.cpp(43): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'editor/editor_scale.h': No such file or directory
rescaler_sse2.c
ssim.c
scons: *** [modules\visual_script\editor\visual_script_property_selector.windows.editor.x86_64.obj] Error 2
modules\visual_script\editor\visual_script_editor.cpp(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'editor/editor_scale.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [modules\visual_script\editor\visual_script_editor.windows.editor.x86_64.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
[Time elapsed: 00:01:38.589]

Thanks for your help !

The command I typed was : scons platform=windows

Comment: If you have problems with compiling godot itself, that may be better asked in their issue tracker, https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues